# Erro ao passar parâmetro através do método GetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, async-await

Como eu passo o objeto `login` como parâmetro para o método `GetAsync` ?
Estou tentando fazer desta maneira, porém não entendi a mensagem de erro:

```
   private async Task<JsonResult> obterLogin(Login login)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpClient httpCliente = new HttpClient();
                    httpCliente.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55838/");
                    httpCliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpCliente.GetAsync("MedClinApi/Login/Obter/ { login }", login);
                    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });      
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

**Print do Erro:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A mensagem é bastante explícita. O método _GetAsync_ espera um parâmetro do tipo _HttpCompletionOption_ e está a ser passado um objeto do tipo _Login_. O método _GetAsync_ não tem assinaturas que permitam passar objetos: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está passando seu parâmetro de forma incorreta, caso você esteja utilizando o C# versão 6 ou superior pode passar parâmetro utilizando string interpolation:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpCliente.GetAsync($"MedClinApi/Login/Obter/{ login }");
```

Caso esteja utilizando uma versão inferior do C#, utilize da seguinte forma:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpCliente.GetAsync(string.Format("MedClinApi/Login/Obter/{0}", login));
```

Dessa forma você vai colocar seu parâmetro na url, porém faz mais sentido você enviar um objeto no corpo da requisição HTTP utilizando o método POST. Se esse serviço for seu sugiro que altere para POST. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(login, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Comment: Olá @Pedro Paulo vou alterar e posto aqui o resultado.

Comment: Beleza, qualquer dúvida estou à disposição.

Comment: deu certo, eu só tive que adequar dessa maneira: `HttpResponseMessage response = await httpCliente.PostAsJsonAsync(url,login);`. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou!